# Impossible Finite State Automata?

Tags: finite-automata

I fully believe this non deterministic FSA is not possible from all of my attempts. The FSA (Non deterministic): A language is made up of an alphabet of only 2's and 3's within strings that have only an odd number of digits (223, 32232) and the sum of the digits must be divisible by 5. (Final inclusion examples: 22222, 33333, 2222322).

Would someone be able to construct this non deterministic FSA with acceptance states graphically? I would be very impressed because from all of both my attempts and also a colleague of mine, the only result is that it cannot be done.

Comment: First write one that accepts odd length. Then write one that accepts numbers whose digit sum is divisible by 5. Then take the product.

Comment: @RaymondChen - I need to have it one the one FSA diagram

Comment: Start with two. Then use standard techniques to merge them into one.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think it is called NFA not FSA. Any regular expression can be converted to an NFA. But not all languages can be specified by REs. Yours may be such an example. Here two simple examples: REs cannot be used to check whether parentheses are balanced or to check whether a string has an equal number of A's and B's. So if you can find an RE for your problem, you are done.

Comment: I get as far as **(22222|33333)*(23|32)+** but I cannot account for the 3's from the ending (23|32) being mixed within any of the first two options in the REs because of the infinite permutations. @Marichyasana